# either syntax issue or wordpress Post ID Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, syntax-error

```
<?php $imvi = get_post_meta('312', 'bmeta_o', true); ?>
```

The above works fine when hardcoded Wordpress post ID is used = '312'

But the theme demands that this should come through some selection of post done in the theme customizer.

I tried various versions →
    $selected_post_id = echo get_theme_mod('my_setting');

```
 1. <?php $imvi = get_post_meta(echo $selected_post_id;, 'bmeta_o',
    true); ?>
 2. <?php $imvi = get_post_meta(echo '', 'bmeta_o', true); ?>
 3. <?php $imvi = get_post_meta($selected_post_id;, 'bmeta_o', true); ?>
```

But none of them worked.

1. either I am not using correct PHP syntax or
2. `$selected_post_id = echo get_theme_mod('my_setting');` → This has
   some flaw and it is not pulling the WordPress post ID correctly

Please let me Know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have `echo` inside the call function and `;`, both of which will cause syntax error.
2. You also have `echo` and just empty string. Will not work.
3. Closest one, but that `;` will still cause an error.
   Correct one (assuming that `$selected_post_id` actually contains post ID)
   `$imvi = get_post_meta($selected_post_id, 'bmeta_o', true);`